# Jenkins Pipeline: exporting and reading environment variable inside bash script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a build pipeline that needs to extract a value from a bit of bash script and use that value elsewhere. I tried to store the result of my bash script in an environment variable like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Break Jenkins') {
            agent any
            steps {    
                sh """
                  ENV_VAR=\$(awk -F'-' '{print \$2 }' <<< \$(ls installer-*-ia32-win.zip))
                  echo $ENV_VAR
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the interpreter hits the `echo $ENV_VAR` line, Jenkins throws an exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ENV_VAR for class: groovy.lang.Binding

I've tried to tell the Jenkins interpreter that `ENV_VAR` isn't a Jenkinsfile environment variable by escaping the dollar sign prefix like this:

```
echo \$ENV_VAR
```

and like this

```
echo '$ENV_VAR'
```

neither works as expected. I think this is an issue with my being inside of a string block (the `sh """ ... """`) syntax, and also telling Jenkins not to try to get the value of `ENV_VAR` out of the `envs` collection.

Anyway, I'm not having much luck googling for the solution to this problem, because Jenkins' pipelines have their own notion of environment variables that seem to be separate from bash environment variables.

It looks like I can only set a Jenkinsfile environment variable inside of an `environment` block, which isn't helpful because I'm already inside of an `sh` block.

Put simply, is there a way to set and access the value of an environment variable from within an `sh` block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double quotes used in `sh` command generates a problem in your case - GString tries to interpret `$ENV_VAR` but there is no such variable defined in current scope. Simple solution to this problem - use single quotes instead.

Also it is worth adding `#!/bin/bash` in the beginning of your script - otherwise you may face failing build with error like:

```
script.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected redirection
```

Below you can find modified pipeline script that worked well in my Jenkins sandbox:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Break Jenkins') {
            agent any
            steps {    
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
                  ENV_VAR=$(awk -F'-' '{print $2 }' <<< $(ls *))
                  echo $ENV_VAR
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course in my case I have simplified `ls` to `$(ls *)` because there are no files that match expression from your example. Hope it helps.

Btw, if you expect your bash script to return something you want to use in your pipeline, you have to execute `sh` in a following way:

```
sh(script: "your script", returnStdout: true)
```

*Reference: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script*

Comment: Hi, this is good info but I have a case that I need literal `$` and I also need interpolation so I'm in a quoting nightmare. Any chance you can provide assistance? https://serverfault.com/questions/948364/jenkins-pipeline-syntax-quoting-pains-when-using-multiple-quote-blocks